# SSH connection with Java

Tags: java, ssh, connection

How can I connect to an SSH server in Java? I don't need/want a shell. I just want to connect to the SSH server and get the content of, say, `file.txt`. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe my solution would be useful - stackoverflow.com/a/59289769/4567218

Answer (score 50):

Use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author World
 */
public class SSHReadFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String user = "john";
        String password = "mypassword";
        String host = "192.168.100.23";
        int port = 22;
        String remoteFile = "/home/john/test.txt";

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
            System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel.connect();
            System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");

            InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);

            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
Establishing Connection...
Connection established.
Crating SFTP Channel.
SFTP Channel created.
This is content from file /home/john/test.txt
```

Comment: Great answer worked for me but just make sure to close everything you open. session.disconnect and sftpChannel.quit .

Comment: When invoking the constructor the following exception is thrown: `GRAVE: JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException durante el procesamiento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=tipoMovimientoGrid:j_idt15, Mensaje=java.lang.ClassCircularityError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException java.lang.ClassCircularityError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
 at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:178)`

Comment: getting the error while trying to connect windows server: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't support that natively, but you can use a library like [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to do it

Answer (score 1):

You must use a third-party library - [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is one of them. Google with "`Java ssh`" and you will get plenty of other options.

Answer (score 1):

You could check [JSSH](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/jssh/), which is a Java SSH library.

Comment: Hi.. I need to add some parameters in my ssh command, like ssh -v user@ip, can u tell me how can I do using this Library

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/ implements a ssh2 client in Java.  I use it for port forwarding.

Comment: " Please note: ETH Zurich does not maintain the code anymore. Please visit the following website, code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/, in case you need updates "

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jaramiko](http://www.lag.net/jaramiko/).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I believe that the sockets have a great deal to do with ssh connections unless you are attempting to do a pre-installed command manipulation application. There are numerous outside packages that you can use to achieve this goal, but if you want to do your own socket creation, it's going to take a large amount of reading and deciphering/encrypting to get this done.

Also creating your own socket is dangerous if not done correctly with the right protocols and security specifications, so be wary about doing so until you are 100% sure you're capable of committing to learning enough.

Answer (score -3):

I used this and worked for me

```
ChannelExec channel=(ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
String command = "Your Command here";
channel.setCommand(command);

InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
channel.setErrStream(System.err);
channel.connect();
```