# how to test file system related behavior and delete the created dir

Tags: unit-testing, junit

My program needs to interact to a directory (with a hierarchical structure) a lot and I need to test it. Therefore, I need to create a directory (and then create sub dirs and files) during the JUnit and then delete this directory after the test.

Is there a good way to do this conveniently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the methods on [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html).  If it isn't a good fit, explain why.

Comment: createTempFile? I want to delete the directory right after my unit test, and this does not seem to do so.

Comment: OK, then you're looking for something that will delete it automatically for you-yes?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your test directory structure in the [BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html)/[Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) JUnit annotated methods and remove them in [AfterClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html)/[After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) (have a look at the JUnit FAQ, e.g. [How can I run setUp() and tearDown() code once for all of my tests?](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#organize_3)).

If [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) does not offer all you need to prepare your directory structure have a look at [com.google.common.io.Files](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/guava/src/com/google/common/io/Files.java) (google guava) or [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) (apache commons io).

Comment: Guava has nothing relevant.  apache does... but from chen's comment on mine, looks like your JUnit point is more on point.

Comment: @Ed Staub Why shouldn't guavas `createParentDirs(File file)`, `createTempDir()`, `deleteDirectoryContents(File directory)` or `deleteRecursively(File file)` be potentially relevant?

Comment: Oops - missed the create methods somehow - thanks, sorry.  I should have known better - whenever I look for anything in Guava that should be there, it nearly always is!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JUnit 4.7, you can use the `TemporaryFolder` rule:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class FooTest {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void doStuffThatTouchesFiles() {
    File root = tempFolder.newFolder("root");
    MyProgram.setRootTemporaryFolder(root);

    ... continue your test
  }
}
```

You could also use the Rule in an `@Before` method. Starting with JUnit 4.9, you will be make the rule field a static, so you could use the rule in a `@BeforeClass` method.

See [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a tem directory.
Take a look at [How to create a temporary directory/folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617414/create-a-temporary-directory-in-java)

If you need to remotely create a directory, connect ssh and do a ssh command

Some ssh libs [SSH Connection Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303122/ssh-connection-java)