# Make SSH Connection and Run An Executable in Java

Tags: java, ssh, executable, jsch

I want to connect to a server using ssh and run an executable on the server from my local Java code. I am aware of the thread [SSH connection with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071760/ssh-connection-with-java) but the trouble is I can not figure out how to use sftpChannel (an object of ChannelSftp) to run a file rather than open a file.

If this can not be done using JSch, how should I do if I want to call a exe file remotely in Java.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ChannelSsh, not ChannelSftp to run a remote command.

http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate a bit more here, firstly are you suggesting using ChannelExec? Then I need to set the commands using void setCommand(String command)? Then calling run()? But how do I get the standard output from this executable?

Comment: ChannelSsh inherits methods for getting the input and output stream for this channel.   One of those will have STDOUT.