# reading logs and displaying them on a web browser using Java

Tags: java, logging

I have logs in folder /home/a/b (located in a remote server)

I want to display logs in my web browser using Java. To get data in the folder /home/a/b and to display them on my web page, what are some methods(API) I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I can imagine is using a SSH API like [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/),
but I don't know how performatic this is.
Anyway, here goes a good example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019095/7528396

Note that you can read the remote file and render line by line.